# Таблица умножения на Python. Помогите разобраться с кодом

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пример взят из книги  Мюллера "Пайтон для чайников". До ### понятно, первый цикл for выводит первую строку с отступом от 1 до 10. Следующий цикл for, выводит строку умножения (потом еще 9), при этом она имеет "заголовок"(Y, первый столбец), а потом непосредственно результат умножения x*y.  И тут не могу понять где в коде есть вывод этого заголовка каждой строки непосредственно перед выводом умножения?

```
X = 1
Y = 1
print ('{:>4}'.format (' '), end= ' ')
for X in range (1, 11):
    print ('{:>4}'.format (X), end= ' ')
print ()
###
for X in range (1, 11):
    print ('{:>4}'.format (X), end= ' ')
    while Y<=10:
        print ('{:>4}'.format (X*Y), end= ' ')
        Y+=1
    print ()
    Y=1
```

так выглядит таблица:

```
        1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
   1    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
   2    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20 
   3    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30 
   4    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40 
   5    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50 
   6    6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54   60 
   7    7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63   70 
   8    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80 
   9    9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81   90 
  10   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100
```

пробовал построчно вводить/запускать код так и не понял. В книге тоже вроде разжеванно построчно, но до меня не дошло.

Comment: см. на строку 9.

Answer (score 3):

Вроде разобрался:
За столбец заголовков отвечает второй цикл for:

```
X = 1
Y = 1
print ('{:>4}'.format (' '), end= ' ')
for X in range (1, 11):
    print ('{:>4}'.format (X), end= ' ')
print ()
for X in range (1, 11):
    print ('{:>4}'.format (X), end= ' ')
    print()
```

возвращет:

```
        1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
   1 
   2 
   3 
   4 
   5 
   6 
   7 
   8 
   9 
  10
```

причем, если убрать табуляцию последней функции print, вернет:

```
      1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
```

а вложенный цикл while вкладывает саму таблицу между заголовками:

```
for X in range (1, 11):
    while Y<=10:
        print ('{:>4}'.format (X*Y), end= ' ')
        Y+=1
    print()
    Y=1
-----------------------------------------------------
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
   2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20 
   3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30 
   4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40 
   5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50 
   6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54   60 
   7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63   70 
   8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80 
   9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81   90 
  10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100
```